# quarkus.http.auth.form.timeout build tipe property

Tags: quarkus

I was wondering why the property *quarkus.http.auth.form.timeout* has to be defined at build time. I would like to change it's value on different installations, and having to rebuild the whole application just for that makes things much more complicated.

Marco.

Comment: I think that this question is more appropiate for the zullip chat of quarkus, there you can talk direclty with the developers of the framework

Comment: Hi kareless, in the zulip chat they state that questions should be asked here, while the chat is for discussions and design decisions. I don't mind writing there, but I don't want to bother people with questions that might not require interaction

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an application.property, have you tried to set the value by an environment variable? eg.

```sh
quarkus.http.auth.form.timeout=${AUTH_FORM_TIMEOUT}
```

This way you could dynamically change it with each deployment with setting `AUTH_FORM_TIMEOUT` to different values.

Comment: Hi Péter,
haven't tried actually, because the documentation says that it's a configuration fixed at build time. So, if I'm not mistaken, it shouldn't be possible to do what you suggest here.

Comment: Yes, you are right! When I first looked it up, I haven't found any reference that this property would be fixed at build time, but now looking again I can see the legend above the property list and the lock icon next to the property. Sorry for that.

Comment: But thinking of it, that also makes sense from a security perspective to lock all security-related features from being modifiable at runtime. In that case if you are using a CI/CD pipeline, you could add parameterized builds for each environment. Most CD pipelines include a build step anyway that rebuilds the project. If you are not using one, depending on the budget of the project maybe you could try a paid or free solution to make your life a bit easier.

Comment: The application is built not only for a cloud environment, but also as a standalone application, and then installed on different client environments. If each one of them wants a different timeout, we would have to create a build for each one. They would also not be able to change it without having us rebuild the whole application. This is not related in any way to the application itself, so from my point of view, I should not need to rebuild it to change the timeout value.

Comment: In that case it seems like a design decision to be discussed on the zullip chat after all :) see if the devs would be open for relaxing security (eg. with a feature switch property that would be off by default and that would make these values overridable at runtime). If not, as a workaround you could separate auth from the application, eg. delegating it to an nginx instance that would be easier to configure with each deployment.